# Semantic UI modal not showing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, ejs, semantic-ui

I've been working on a project that requires a Semantic UI modal (pop up) to show if I click the "View Details" button, but every time the modal pops up, it is positioned weirdly and I can't do anything with it (eg can't close it)
[image]

Here is my .ejs file and the script part of it

```
<% include header.ejs %>
<% include nav.ejs %>
<div class="page-hero" style="background-image: url('004.jpg'); width: 100%;">
<h1 id="eachTitle">MY PROFILE</h1>
</div>
<div class="ui container">
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..." required class="searchBook">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
<% for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){ %>
    <div class="ui grid">
        <div class="column four wide">
            <div class="ui card">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src = "<%= results[i].thumbnail %>"/>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="header">
                        <h1 class="ui small header title"><%= results[i].title %></h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="meta">
                        <p>Author: <%= results[i].authors %></p>
                        <p>Published on: <%= results[i].publishedDate %></p>
                        <p>Pages: <%= results[i].pageCount %></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content extra">
                    <button class="ui button fluid" id="detail">View Detail</button>
                    <button class="ui button fluid" type="button" name="button">Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="modaldiv" class="ui modal">
        <i class="close icon"></i>
        <div class="header">
            Book info
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="discription">
                <div class="ui header">Book Description</div>
                <p><%= results[i].description%></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <div class="ui button">Delete</div>
        </div>
    </div>
<% } %>


</div>
<% include footer.ejs%>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click', '#detail', function(){
    $('.ui.modal').modal('show');
});
})

</script>
```

Everything is defined and the console shows no errors

(Also if I render more than one book and try to click the view details button, the page just turns black, but I think that is a loop error)
Does anyone know why it happens and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem comes from this loop :

> for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++).

You initialize multiples modals with the same ID and Class name so when you try to open it I think he want to open all the modals and that's not good.

> $('.ui.modal').modal('show');

Try to look your console to verify it. 
Otherwise, create different class name or id name for each modal you create and it will be fix I think.

Peace

Comment: No problems, if you need more on modal just ask ;)